# How to read all the data of unknown length from a StreamSocket in WinRT using DataReader

Tags: sockets, windows-runtime, winjs, winrt-async

I have configured my socket to read partial data too like this:

```
@socket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket()
hostName = new Windows.Networking.HostName(@ip)
@ensureConnection = @socket.connectAsync(hostName, @port.toString())
.then () =>
  @writer = new DataWriter(@socket.outputStream)
  @reader = new DataReader(@socket.inputStream)
  @reader.inputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.partial
```

Then my function to read from the socket looks like this:

```
readLineAsync = (reader, buffer = "") ->
while reader.unconsumedBufferLength
  byte = reader.readByte()
  if byte is 0
    return WinJS.Promise.as(buffer)
  buffer += String.fromCharCode(byte)
reader.loadAsync(1024).then (readBytes) ->
  if readBytes is 0
    WinJS.Promise.as(buffer)
  else
    while reader.unconsumedBufferLength
      byte = reader.readByte()
      if byte is 0
        return WinJS.Promise.as(buffer)
      buffer += String.fromCharCode(byte)
    readLineAsync(reader, buffer)
```

There are 2 problems with this function:

1. With very large responses, the stack builds up with recursive readLineAsync calls. How can I prevent that? Should I use the WinJS Scheduler API or similar to queue the next call to `readLineAsync`?
2. Sometimes the reader.loadAsync does not finish when no data is on the socket anymore. Sometimes it does and `readByte` is 0 then. Why is that?

Why do I loop over the reader's uncunsumedBufferLength on 2 locations in that function? I initially had this code in the loadAsync continuation handler. But since a response can contain a terminating `\0` char I need to check for unread data in the readers buffer upon function entry too.

Thats the pseudo loop to send/receive to/from the socket:

```
readResponseAsync = (reader) ->
  return readLineAsync(@reader).then (line) ->
    result = parseLine(line)
    if result.unknown then return readResponseAsync(reader)
    return result

@ensureConnection.then () =>
  sendCommand(...)

  readResponseAsync(@reader).then (response) ->
    # handle response
```

All the WinRT samples from MS deal with known amount of data on the socket, so they not really fit my scenario.

Comment: `DataReader.LoadAsync()` internally calls socket's `IInputStream.ReadAsync()`. If it block, it means there is no data available. It will return until there is at least one byte to return. If it returns zero bytes, then it means the underlying stream was closed (no more to read).

Comment: But the `InputStreamOptions.partial` should also return when there is nothing to read, shouldn't it? If not how can I prevent running into this kind of "blocked" situation in my scenario? As I said, I do not know the amount of data the server is going to send.

Comment: No, the `InputStreamOptions.partial` should not return with zero bytes unless the stream is over. You can [cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj150586.aspx) the `LoadAsync()`/`ReadAsync()` operation, but notice the socket will be closed too.

Comment: I am still not sure how I detect if the stream is over. Should I use a timeout? The code I am porting used sockets and `ioctlsocket(sock, FIONREAD, &num_to_read)` with a timeout if no bytes could be read after a certain amount of ms.

Comment: I guess there is no equivalent to that in WinRT Sockets. The answer will depend on the Application Layer protocol. What is the protocol? Does the other peer is supposed to send a FIN at some point? That would close the input stream.

Comment: I am not sure about the other peer. From the old sync code I can see they try to read data from the socket until a `\0` terminates a chunk or they waited for 5 secs on the socket to get new data. If it times out, the assume that the data was completely transmitted. So I will wrap my `loadAsync` call like this: `WinJS.Promise.timeout(reader.loadAsync(1024), 5000).then () -> return buffer, (error) -> if error.name is "Canceled" return buffer else return WinJS.Promise.wrapError(error)`